# import.io: get input value that is out of the <tr>

Tags: jquery, html, import.io

I want to extract data from a html table.

The hard thing, that one of the needed column data is before the actual row, here you can see on the screenshot:

[image]

Do you have any idea how to get value of the hidden input in the actual table row?

Comment: Technically this HTML structure is invalid, so when the browser renders this it shuffles things around in its internal DOM. Try extracting the inputs as children (any depth) of the table or the table's parent element. E.g. In jQuery: `var inputs = $('table :input');`

Comment: Of course I should have mentioned... If you have any ability to fix the HTML source code to make it valid, do that instead/first.

Comment: I am on it, in the meantime any suggestions to fix this invalid code are welcomed. Bash/Linux is prefered, because I download pages from CLI.

Comment: Ah yeah if you are just scraping the HTML via command line scripts then I would try to get an "array" of the rows in the table and an "array" of the inputs in the table... Then associate the data from each row to the same index in the array of inputs. This will be 'fragile' code as any deviation from this pattern will create bad or missing associations but it sounds like this is the best you can do with what you have. :-(

Comment: Can you post the URL of the site that gives you this issue? Import.io should do the "shuffling" as mentioned above because it renders html/javascript on the backend. It would be helpful to see how the page is rendering this, it's likely you would have to use a custom xpath to grab the hidden value.

Comment: Sure, here it is: http://hopp.mihalko.eu/1PRSfFY. In the meantime I found another method (I am extracting the id from image url), but any other solution are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get some values using XPaths.

Train each row as usual using the mouse cursor. It will capture the header as well so in Row Training set skip to 2.

Then you can give the following XPaths

**ids:** `(.//preceding::input[contains(@name, "id")]/@value)[last()]`

**name:** `(.//td[@class="cart-data"])[3]`

**price:** `(.//td[@class="cart-data"])[6]`

[image]